# MS Access link to a Data Service (SQL Server) via WCF

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Our client has an MS Access application which we want to link to a SQL Server database.
We want to write some sort of WCF service to provide the Access Database with the correct data from our SQL Server.

But where should I start with this?
And suppose I already have create the service.

Why can't I add any external services in my Access app?
It's greyed out and I haven't got a clue why.

[image: Imgur]

Does anyone have experiences with this type of solution?

Comment: I believe that the Data Services option is only available from `.accdb` files and is greyed out for `.mdb` files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone does have experience as to do it in Access would be very difficult. You can create Linked tables in access, which look just like Access Tables, but are actually linked to a table in a SQL Server db, but that's not what you want. There is no 'natural' way to link a table to a WCF Service.

However, it might be possible, with an enormous amount of work, that you could call the WCF service and unserialise the returned XML data via VBA code within the Access application. I would not personally attempt it, and would discourage all but my worst enemies from doing so.

Comment: I'm still having no luck to even find docs around this. 
Could my problem be solved if the Access app uses linked tables to a remote Sql Server? Can that be done? And how secure would that be?

Comment: Linked Tables are quite secure, I believe. Have a google about them.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I add any external services in my Access app? It's greyed out and I haven't got a clue why.

The "Data Services" option is only available from within `.accdb` files. It is greyed out if an `.mdb` file is open.